# Using Lombok, method are not resolve

Tags: java, lombok

In class Car and add annotation

```
@Entity
@Getter @Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString @EqualsAndHashCode

public class Car {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    Long id;
    @NotNull String name;
}
```

In another class i create object car

```
Car car = new Car();
```

and try using setter

```
car.setName("Toyota");
```

but i have error that cannot resolve method 'setName()' 
getters also don't work.

Comment: can you show us your dependency ? and the import as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using intellij,follow this [guide](https://projectlombok.org/setup/intellij)

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't want to use the plugin you can enable "annotation processing" . Here is a link:https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-annotation-processing.html